# How should I submit bug reports and feature requests?

Tags: macos, ios, bug, software

Inspired by [Marco Ceppi's DS_store question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11780/never-create-a-ds-store-file-again) I became curious about what is the current preferred mechanism for submitting bug reports and feature requests to Apple. I'm aware that they have the internal RDAR bug tracking system, and that there is an [Open RDAR](http://openradar.appspot.com/) project to crowdsource the tracking of issues, but I'm at a loss as to the preferred channel to submit something.

Is there a public-facing portal for submitting issues?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apple offers a [feedback site](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) where both bug reports and feature requests can be submitted by anyone. Be sure to describe the issue or feature as clearly and concisely as possible.

Developers should use [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/). If you carefully describe the issue including step by step instructions for reproducing the problem, they tend to get attention and fixed. You'll need an ADC (Apple Developer Connection) login to use the bug reporting system. Be sure to upload the System Profiler report, as well as any crash logs which may be relevant.