# How do I report a bug in Safari 6.0?

Tags: safari, bug

I found a bug in the latest version of Safari, how can I report it to Apple?

They no longer have the menu option to submit bug reports. I've tried searching Google but all the results are outdated.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11789/how-should-i-submit-bug-reports-and-feature-requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://bugreport.apple.com is the canonical bug reporting mechanism. Once you have submitted an issue, it will be given a "radar" number and you will be treated to possibly the most archaic customer-facing bug reporting interfaces on the planet.

You will want to first select a developer account and agree to Apple's terms. In your case, the free of cost Safari developer program might be very useful if you care to know what changes are in store for Safari.

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action

Answer (score 3):

The [OS X Feedback page](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html) has a bug report option (under "Feedback Type"). There's also http://bugreporter.apple.com, but I can't recall if that's limited to those with a Developer account (which is free to get).

Comment: Becoming a developer is still free and you are correct that you must sign up as a developer (there is a Safari Developer program in fact which would be ideal for the OP in this case.)

Comment: @bmike: is it free to submit a bug through the Safari Developer program? Is there a direct link to there, or will I see it once I login to the above link?

Comment: Yes - becoming a Safari developer is free of cost and you do not need to pay to submit bug reports. You can learn more here: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action

Comment: @bmike: I joined the program, but the only reference I saw there to bug reporting just takes you to the bugreporter.apple.com link above. Am I missing something?

Comment: Once you are enrolled as a developer, that Apple ID will allow you to log into the bug reporting web site. Click on the "report a new problem" http://cl.ly/ILlc and see what data is needed to submit a bug report. Compose all the info offline in TextEdit or something and paste it into the form when you are ready to submit. The web site is notorious for timing out and eating a submission that takes more than 10 minutes to file...

Comment: @bmike: Oh I see, I thought you meant that the Safari Developer program has a special site designed for bug reporting, but that is not the case. It uses the same one as bugreporter.apple.com, but you need an apple developer ID to access that website, so it would be a good idea to sign up as a Safari developer since that is the product I'm experiencing a problem with anyways.