# How to sort by priority in iOS Reminders app?

Tags: ios, reminders

The ability to automatically sort items by priority on desktop is an useful feature. It keeps them on top in list view reminding that most urgent tasks are to be completed first. Therefore, lack of it on mobile is that much apparent.

---

iOS version: 11.2.6 (15D100)

Comment: Are you open to trying 3rd-party apps that allow this?  Also, what version of iOS are you using.  See [ask] for useful info on asking questions.

Comment: @fsb thanks for reaching out. I agree with the guidelines. However, I'm convinced this is more of a yes–no question. So I do not see how I could expand it. As far as alternatives go, do you know about one that also has archival and 'remind at a location' features?

Comment: The answer is 'No, it can't be done with the current Reminders'.  If you're open to alternatives, you can try to open a new question or use the [SE software recommendation site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, the feature **is not** available.

You might want to try requesting it through Apple’s [feedback site](https://www.apple.com/feedback/). For more details on how see "[How should I submit bug reports and feature requests?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/11789/199028)" And make sure to read [Unsolicited Idea Submission Policy](https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/policies/ideas.html) prior to sharing any information.

Comment: Looks like there is no selectable iOS reminders topic?