# Need help to submit a bug report

Tags: ios, bug

I’ve spotted a bug in iOS, but I don’t feel confident enough in my English to report it in detail.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Can’t post this in chat because of insufficient reputation; please refer me as the moderators would deem appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How should I submit bug reports and feature requests?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11789/how-should-i-submit-bug-reports-and-feature-requests?rq=1)

Comment: If you wrote the question without the assistance of a translation tool, your English is going to be good enough for a bug report. Even if you did use a translation tool, screenshots, videos, code samples should be provided anyways and will help explain the issue. So please go for it!