# Where should I report a icloud.com bug?

Tags: icloud, bug

I can reproduce a non-security bug in icloud.com/notes. The Feedback Assistant does not however give any specific option for icloud.com bug reports as you can see from the image. Web Services & SDKs might be the closest to the issue but they really are a different area.

I am on Windows 11 using Google Chrome.

Where should I file my bug report?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate? [How should I submit bug reports and feature requests?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11789/how-should-i-submit-bug-reports-and-feature-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a form on https://www.apple.com/feedback/icloud.html that covers Notes & also Windows.

I'd first try to repro on something other than Chrome, to eliminate it as a factor.

Comment: Good catch on the Notes and Windows part! Do you think this is a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11789/how-should-i-submit-bug-reports-and-feature-requests ?

Comment: Potentially. I'll link them & see what others think...