# How to stop folders being modified when you look in them?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

When I open a folder, the "date modified" date changes. This is annoying if nothing in the folder has changed. I like to search for things by reverse "date modified" order, i.e. listing things that I have changed recently at the top.

Is there a way of changing this behavior so that the folder's "date modified" reflects the last time something changed in the folder?

ETA. To modify the question a bit, is it possible to change the "date modified" of the folder back to the newest "date modified" of it's contents?

Answer (score 2):

Simply looking in a folder doesn't change the date modified. This only happens if Finder makes a change in the folder, for example to create a missing .DS_Store file. It's not possible to disable the creation of .DS_Store files for local volumes using Finder, see [Never create a .DS_Store file again](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11780/never-create-a-ds-store-file-again).

Comment: Hmm. The folders I am looking at are old work from a backup. They probably don't have .DS_Store files and so that explains why their date modified is changing. I'll edit the question.