# Preventing Finder from changing "Date Modified" attribute

Tags: icloud, finder, command-line

Finder has a pesky trait where sometimes it would set `Date Modified` to today's when browsing a really old folder.

For the time being, I am using attribute `Date Modified` as a quick guidance when looking for something.

To preserve `Date Modified` attribute, I am using `sudo chflags -R uchg <folder>` and `sudo chflags -R schg <folder` *inside iCloud Drive folders*.

Actual question - are there any issues/risks/problems when using `sudo chflags -R schg <folder>` and `sudo chflags -R uchg <folder>` *inside iCloud Drive folder*?

Ps. I realize that setting these flags will prevent me from making any edits (i.e. access will be read-only for my user **and** the system); that's my intention, I want to treat certain folders as true archives - i.e. no edits whatsoever even to attributes

Comment: It's probably because Finder creates `.DS_Store`. Try to prevent it from being created. See e.g. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32263/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-those-pesky-ds-store-files-from-being-ever-created, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015978/how-to-stop-creating-ds-store-on-mac

Comment: I have seen those answers actually, but I do not feel that comfortable modifying the core or disabling SIP or messing with integrity of OS in general