# How to UNDO stopping OS X from writing Spotlight and Trash files?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, trash

I tried stopping OS X from writing Spotlight and Trash files to a memory card.
The method by Metaxis to the question here "How to stop OS X from writing Spotlight and Trash files to memory cards and USB sticks?" works fine and I have used it many times, but this time I wasn't paying attention and have addressed the wrong folder.
[The question how to stop in the original post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6707/how-to-stop-os-x-from-writing-spotlight-and-trash-files-to-memory-cards-and-usb)

This is what I did including the responses and replacing my first name with first name and full name with myfullname:

```
MBP-van-firstname:~ myfullname$ mdutil -i off /Volumes/SD128MB
/Volumes/SD128MB:
2016-03-02 22:57:40.638 mdutil[1232:208844] mdutil disabling Spotlight: /Volumes/SD128MB -> kMDConfigSearchLevelFSSearchOnly
Indexing disabled.
MBP-van-firstname:~ myfullname$ rm -rf .{,_.}{fseventsd,Spotlight-V*,Trashes}
MBP-van-firstname:~ myfullname$ mkdir .fseventsd
MBP-van-firstname:~ myfullname$ touch .fseventsd/no_log .metadata_never_index .Trashes
MBP-van-firstname:~ myfullname$ cd -
-bash: cd: OLDPWD not set
```

So, where the action were supposed to happen in the targeted folder, they were in the wrong folder. How can I undo this?

Answer (score 2):

What Metaxis described looks like it can be reverted with the following:

```
mdutil -i on /Volumes/yourUSBstick
cd /Volumes/yourUSBstick
rm -rf .fseventsd/no_log .metadata_never_index .Trashes
cd -
```

The first line with `mdutil` is the most important if you want your volume to index again, as it sets the indexing status for the volume back to on, according to the manual:

```
-i on | off
     Sets the indexing status for the provided volumes to on or off.  Note that indexing may be delayed due to
     low disk space or other conditions.
```

#### EDIT:

in your case (but this is specific to OP), you forgot to `cd` (*change directory*) into the volume before deleting the index files and adding a few files. You just need to delete the files you created locally (in your home folder):

```
rm -r .fseventsd/no_log .metadata_never_index .Trashes
```

No need to use `mdutil` to re-enable indexing on your drive as you did the first command right and only did a mistake after the second command.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you did was create some files.  You can just delete them.

```
rm -r .fseventsd
rm .metdata_never_inded
rm .Trashes
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the files as LaX (and iWill) described.